# Do nginx questions belong here or on serverfault?

Tags: discussion

At the moment, I see 85 questions tagged [nginx](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nginx), while Serverfault has [6,775](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nginx). StackOverflow has [double that number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx).

Answer (score 3):

As webmaster use webservers, which are servers, there's always an overlap between this site and that. If it's a question which a webmaster needs to know the answer to, and the technology they happen to be using is nginx then it probably belongs here. If it's a more detailed question that a server expert would ask then it probably belongs there. Choose one site and if it's in appropriate it will get moved. You won't get penalised.